# Highlight multiple overlapping matches in a string (Javascript) and display in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, include

I am trying to identify multiple matches in a string then highlight the results using a span class.
The issue is where matches overlap. 'abc' matches without any problem, but 'cde' doesn't because a '/span' is now present in the string.

```js
var search_array = ['abc', '123', 'cde'];

var string_to_be_searched = 'abcdef123';

$.each(search_array, function(index, value) {
  if (string_to_be_searched.includes(value)) {
    string_to_be_searched = string_to_be_searched.replace(value, '<span class="highlight">' + value + '</span>');
  }
})

$('div').html(string_to_be_searched);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it to be a [mcve] - for example is `Replace` not a jQuery or JavaScript method. JS would be `string_to_be_searched = string_to_be_searched.replace(from,to)` and you are not actually doing anything in your loop with whatever you are replacing

Comment: Why not using another string to save the span tag with the values instead of replacing it?

Comment: You might want to check first of any values within the `search_array` have any overlap.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for the coding error which I've now fixed. - I'm new to this!. The result I'm looking for is all the text to be highlighted except the 'f'. As it stands at the moment only 'abc' and '123' are highlighted

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` is not a know function in JS or jQuery. Also normal replace is not an in-place method

```js
const search_array = ['abc', '123', 'cde'];
let string_to_be_searched = 'abcdef123';

search_array.forEach(str => string_to_be_searched = string_to_be_searched.replaceAll(str,`<span class="highlight">${str}</span>`))


$('div').html(string_to_be_searched);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: But OP asking for highlighting overlapping matches. OP needs to highlight both `abc` and `cde`

Comment: That is exactly right. The only letter that shouldn't be highlighted is 'f'

Answer (score 0):

Just append your match result on `div`.

```js
var search_array = ['abc', '123', 'cde'];

var string_to_be_searched = 'abcdef123';
$.each(search_array, function(index, value) {
  if (string_to_be_searched.includes(value)) {
    $('div').append($('<span class="highlight">').text(value));
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not quite wat I was looking for. I'm hoping to find a way to highlight 'abcdde' and '123' so only 'f' is not highlighted. I want to leave the characters in the string unchanged